# Javascript - Need to reset all page elements before calling function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates a random schedule. On the click of a button, I want to reset all values and recreate another schedule. Instead of reinitializing all of my elements to their original values, I found it to be easier to reload the page.  When I have two separate buttons, one that generates, the schedule and one that reloads, this works perfectly.

However, I need one button to do both, but when I call reload at the beginning of the function, the schedule gets populated and is automatically reloaded again.

```
function generateSchedule() {

    window.location.reload();

    for (var i = 0; exams_scheduled.length < TOTAL_EXAMS; i++){

        var time = randomNumber(3); // 3 exam timeslots per day
        var day = randomNumber(6); // 6 exam days per week
        var week = randomNumber(2); // 2 week period

        var weekday = day + '' + week; 
        var exam_id = "exam-" + time + '' + weekday; 

    if ((exam_count[weekday] < EXAMS_PER_DAY) && (!exams_scheduled.includes(exam_id))) {
        exam_count[weekday] += 1;
        exams_scheduled.push(exam_id);

        document.getElementById(exam_id).className += "exam";   
    }
  }  
}
```

Here is a codepen that calls reload at the beginning of the generate function. As you can see, the schedule is generated and automatically reloaded again.

http://codepen.io/skyro/pen/apQwWY

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Provide jsfiddle.

Comment: codepen provided, kind user

Comment: You could check `window.location.search` for `?reload` and then execute the function

Comment: What's the problem with removing a css class (simple loop, `document.getElementsByClassName()`/`document.querySelectorAll()`), resetting all values in an object (simple loop, `for...in...`/`Object.keys()`) and emptying an array (`.length = 0`)? ([codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPVWPV))

Comment: I was looking for a cheap alternative

Comment: Codepen edited to show issue

Comment: Did you check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPVWPV)? It's using ES6 features but those 3 lines won't be much different with ES5

Comment: It's broken. Page keeps reloading on its own

Answer (score 0):

Well from what i could understand is that you want the button to reload your page but right after it does that it calls out the new schedule, is that right?
If so you can use the `window.onload` on the schedule so that it is automatically summoned right after the page loads?
Or maybe...
The `setTimeout(callNewSchedule, 100)` function would be useful
by simply setting a delay from when the button was triggered. Doubt this would work though. Coz as soon as that page reloads it looses all of its previous data and the `setTimeout` function would never happen.
ergo the `onload` is the best choice in this matter.

Comment: `window.onload = generateSchedule();` Put that after `function generateSchedule()` your code and you're done. Hope this helps

Comment: `window.onload = generateSchedule();` won't do what you think it would do... ;)

Comment: did you put it at the very bottom coz if you put it at the top it won't work at all :3

Comment: If you put it at the bottom you don't need `window.onload` at all... `window.onload = generateSchedule();` this will assign the return value `undefined` of the immediately executed function `generateSchedule()` as the `onload` handler - hence it's simply wrong.

Comment: oh yeah... huh... guess that info i got a few hours ago was wrong about onload header and footer thing... thanks for clearing that up too before i used it.

Answer (score 0):

Took a while but seems like it works. You don't have to reload the page now to get new values.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const EXAMS_PER_DAY = 2;
const TOTAL_EXAMS = 5;

var exam_days = {
  00: 0,
  10: 0,
  20: 0,
  30: 0,
  40: 0,
  50: 0,
  01: 0,
  11: 0,
  21: 0,
  31: 0,
  41: 0,
  51: 0
};

var exam_array = [];

function generateSchedule() {
  exam_array = [];
  var c = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1]];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < c[0].length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < c[1].length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < c[2].length; k++) {
        b = `${c[0][i]}${c[1][j]}${c[2][k]}`;
        document.getElementById('exam-' + b).style.background = 'transparent';
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; exam_array.length < TOTAL_EXAMS; i++) {

    var time = getRandomInt(0, 2);
    var day = getRandomInt(0, 5);
    var week = getRandomInt(0, 1);

    var exam_id = "exam-" + time + day + week;
    if (exam_days[day + '' + week] < EXAMS_PER_DAY && !exam_array.includes(exam_id)) {
      exam_days[day + '' + week] += 1;
      exam_array.push(exam_id);
      document.getElementById(exam_id).style.background = "green";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th scope="col">M</th>
    <th scope="col">T</th>
    <th scope="col">W</th>
    <th scope="col">R</th>
    <th scope="col">F</th>
    <th scope="col">S</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Morning</th>
    <td id="exam-000"></td>
    <td id="exam-010"></td>
    <td id="exam-020"></td>
    <td id="exam-030"></td>
    <td id="exam-040"></td>
    <td id="exam-050"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Afternoon</th>
    <td id="exam-100"></td>
    <td id="exam-110"></td>
    <td id="exam-120"></td>
    <td id="exam-130"></td>
    <td id="exam-140"></td>
    <td id="exam-150"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Evening</th>
    <td id="exam-200"></td>
    <td id="exam-210"></td>
    <td id="exam-220"></td>
    <td id="exam-230"></td>
    <td id="exam-240"></td>
    <td id="exam-250"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th scope="col">M</th>
    <th scope="col">T</th>
    <th scope="col">W</th>
    <th scope="col">R</th>
    <th scope="col">F</th>
    <th scope="col">S</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Morning</th>
    <td id="exam-001"></td>
    <td id="exam-011"></td>
    <td id="exam-021"></td>
    <td id="exam-031"></td>
    <td id="exam-041"></td>
    <td id="exam-051"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Afternoon</th>
    <td id="exam-101"></td>
    <td id="exam-111"></td>
    <td id="exam-121"></td>
    <td id="exam-131"></td>
    <td id="exam-141"></td>
    <td id="exam-151"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Evening</th>
    <td id="exam-201"></td>
    <td id="exam-211"></td>
    <td id="exam-221"></td>
    <td id="exam-231"></td>
    <td id="exam-241"></td>
    <td id="exam-251"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<button onclick="generateSchedule();">Generate</button>
<button onclick="location.reload(true);">Reload</button>
<button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
```